# Set style background-image on react component

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I'm using an inline style to change avatar background-image.

```
const avatarStyle ={
  backgoundImage: "url('/images/22.jpg')"
};

const avatar() = () => <div style={avatarStyle}></div>
```

But this code doesn't set any style on this tag.

Comment: you misspelled background yo, looks fine otherwise

Comment: Does your `<div>` have any content, or a fixed height/width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed letter `r` on `backgroundImage`

I think this will work for you,

```
const avatarStyle ={
  backgroundImage: "url('/images/22.jpg')"
};

const avatar() = () => <div style={avatarStyle}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine. You just made a typo on line 2.
Try this

```
const avatarStyle ={
  backgroundImage: "url('/images/22.jpg')"
};

const avatar() = () => <div style={avatarStyle}></div>
```